# using selenium in python to loop through keys in csv and download pdf

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to use selenium in Python to take information from a city's public website and loop through information I have in a csv with each row being a different address, date and city. Ideally I would download the associated PDF, but I am getting stuck on how to actively loop through the csv using pandas. I pasted the code I have so far!

```
import pandas as pd
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\uof_ex.csv')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://p2c.highpointnc.gov/EventSearch')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait_implicit = driver.implicitly_wait(5)
action = ActionChains(driver)

pop_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="disclaimerDialog"]/md-dialog-actions/button[2]'))).click()

i = 0
while i == 0:
    a = 0
    address = df.address
    city = df.City
    date = df.date_occu

    search_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="byReportInformation-card"]/md-card-title/md-card-title-text/span[1]'))).click()
    time.sleep(2)
    address_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="address-input"]')))
    address_element.click()
    address_element.clear()
    address_element.send_keys(address[a])
    time.sleep(2)
    city_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="city-select"]'))).click()
    city_element_choose = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="select_option_24"]'))).click() 
    time.sleep(2)
    stdate_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_6"]'))).click()
    stdate_element_clear = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_6"]'))).clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    enddate_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_8"]'))).click()
    enddate_element_clear = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_8"]'))).clear()
    time.sleep(2)
    stdate_element_choose = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_6"]'))).send_keys(date[a])
    enddate_element_choose = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="input_8"]'))).send_keys(date[a])

    search_element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="search-button"]'))).click()
        
    time.sleep(2)
    
    back_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//*[@id="back-button"]'))).click()
    
    time.sleep(2)
    
    a = a + 1
```

Comment: IMO, this is not the time to be using a `while` loop, in fact, its almost never is the time to use them. Use a `for` loop to iterate over your DataFrame like this: `for index, row in df.iterrows():` then you can use `row['address']`, etc in your searches

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can loop over the rows of the pandas csv object

as named tuples

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\uof_ex.csv')
for row in df.itertuples():
    address = row.address
    city = row.City
    date = row.date_occu
```

now `address` contains the data from the currently iterated row. so you can use `address` directly instead of `address[i]`.

or as dictionaries

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    address = row['address']
    city = row['City']
    date = row['date_occu']
```

read here for more options https://www.dataindependent.com/pandas/pandas-iterate-over-rows/